# Error in powershell: operation requires an interactive window station

Tags: powershell

I am executing the below command through autosys(scheduling tool) to stop a service, but it is failing with below error. 
The command works fine when I run the command on RUN(WIN+R) or cmd after RDPing into the server. Can anyone help me here?

```
Command: C:\windows\System32\...powershell Start-Process powershell -Verb runAs E:\ABC\stop_service.ps1

Content of stop_service.ps1 = stop-service -name 'service-abc'
```

Error:

> Start-Process : This command cannot be run due to the error: This operation requires an interactive window station.
>
> At line:1 char:1
>   + Start-Process powershell -Verb runAs
>   E:\ABC\stop_service.ps ...
>   + ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
>   + CategoryInfo : InvalidOperation: (:) [Start-Process], InvalidOp
>   erationException
>   + FullyQualifiedErrorId : InvalidOperationException,Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.StartProcessCommand

Comment: Remove `-Verb runas`.

Comment: -Verb runas is for running the command in elevated(admin) powershell. Command is failing with 'Access denied' on removing it.

Comment: Set the scheduled task to run elevated ("run with highest privileges") instead.

Comment: can you suggest what command should i run or what change should i make in above command ?  The autosys just simply execute the same command but this time it is giving error "operation requires an interactive window station"

Comment: Ask this question on superuser or serverfault. Stackoverflow is for programming/development questions.

Comment: @bill Well does powershell is not a programming language? https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/322196

Comment: I end up here with the same question, you may want to have look at this two related post
https://serverfault.com/a/993517/373979 and https://serverfault.com/a/974080/373979

Comment: PowerShell can be used to write scripts, but it is also an interactive shell. That's the topic of the question here: The above is related to a question about a PowerShell command, not really a script as such.